# See if value exists in deep nested json array

Tags: php, arrays

Here I have my simple json response:

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [id] => 3
            [type] => workspace
            [attributes] => Array
                (
                    [name] => testing
                    [slug] => testing
                    [data] =>
                    [created_at] => 
                    [updated_at] => 
                    [role] => Amazing
                    [last_accessed_at] =>
                )

        )

)
```

Is it possible to make a generic function that would simply look for the given value within the given path?.

For example I would like to make a function that would recursively search for a given value with a given key:

```
public function seeIfValueExistsInJson("data.attributes.slug", "testing"){

}
```

I would like to make it as generic as possible encase the first item of the response was not "data" and could be something else.

Has anyone seen/made anything similar and would be willing to share?

Thank you :)

---

Update:
I have technically managed to do this. But I know this is not the best way possible as it just doesn't feel or look like it, and I would love to see your criticism on how it can be improved to help me improve my code even further:

```
public function extractData($fullPath, $value)
    {

        $jsonString = json_encode($this->json());
        $paths = explode(".", $fullPath);
        $oldPos = 0;
        $len = sizeof($paths) - 1;
        foreach ($paths as $path) {
            if (strpos($jsonString, $path) !== false) {
                $currPos = strpos($jsonString, $path);
                if ($currPos > $oldPos) {
                    if ($len === 0) {
                        $valuePos = strpos($jsonString, $value);
                        PHPUnit::assertTrue($currPos < $valuePos);
                        break;
                    }
                    $len--;
                }
                $oldPos = $currPos;
            } else {
                print("The path: '$path' is not within this Json response");
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see this function turns the given response json into a string and gets the positions of each of the "path" indexs you give it (after exploding them) and then makes sure that the previous position of the index was smaller than the next (this way it means the next index path you are looking for has to be after) and then once it has reached the end of the loop it will (in my case using phpunit) assert that the value you have given is further along the list than the last index path. This does seem to have many flaws in terms of same string being in the response etc. So I would be welcoming to any feeback on how I could improve this

Comment: Hi, could you add what you've tried so far? Stackoverflow is not a free coding service. Please try to solve your problem yourself and come back with a question regarding actual code. Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find a key in nested json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36885574/find-a-key-in-nested-json)

Comment: Since JSON is merely a string, you could just see if the JSON string contains the value that you want, then if it does, perform any logic from there...

Comment: Yes of course, sorry. I have tried manually creating my own function to find if the first array is the same as the one given and if it is then proceed to the next but got stuck and could not continue further. Tried using a combination of different array_ functions with no avail

Comment: @TobyR You should definitely add the other code you've tried, and how your attempts went wrong: include what error messages they gave or how their output deviated from your desired result.

Comment: I have updated it for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you already have an array, you can explode `$fullPath` and search each of the keys in that array. If there is no such key, return `false`. Else, check if the value of the path is equal with `$value`:

```
$arr = ['data' => ['id' => 3, 'type' => 'workspace',
        'attributes' => ['name'=>'testing', 'slug'=>'testing', 
                         'data' => '', 'created_at' =>'',
                         'updated_at' => '', 'role' => 'Amazing',
                         'last_accessed_at' => '']]];

function seeIfValueExistsInJson($arr, $fullPath, $value){
    $tempArr = $arr;
    $keys = explode('.', $fullPath);
    foreach($keys as $key){
      if(isset($tempArr[$key])){
          $tempArr = $tempArr[$key];
      }
      else return false;
    }
    return $tempArr === $value;
}

$result = seeIfValueExistsInJson($arr, "data.attributes.slug", "testing");
echo 'Result: ' . $result;
```

This will return:

```
Result: 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I strongly recommend *against* encoding the string as JSON and then searching the JSON.  This strategy won't work in a generic sense.  You need to traverse the data structure, probably using some kind of recursive function. *(Which I won't attempt to write here.)*

If the data comes in as JSON, you should first decode it into a data structure.  (Treat the JSON string as a "black box.")

Comment: I understand that you would strongly recommend against it as there obviously are a lot of flaws and issues with this. Which is why I was trying to find another way :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use [array_walk_recursive](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-walk-recursive.php) PHP function.

```
<?php
$data = json_decode($json);
$hasData = false;
$searchString = "";
array_walk_recursive($data, function($value, $key) {
    $hasData = $hasData || $value == $searchString;
});
```

PS.: You may need to add a few tweaks for type checking. =D

PS. 2: I wasn't able to test this because I'm not on my PC atm.